# Filter lines of TSV file that have a number on third column

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a TSV file like this:

```
análisis de elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  4
análisis de elementos finitos
elemento finito http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  5
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
elementos finitos
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
finite element method   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos
finite element method
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  7
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos
método de los elementos

análisis 5 de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método3_de_los_elementos_finitos 4
elemento 4 finito   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de4_los_elementos_finitos 5
elementos3 finitos  http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
finite element-1 method http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  2
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método5_de_los_elementos5_finitos    7
```

I want to filter that file only with the lines that have a number at the end (third column):

```
análisis de elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  4
elemento finito http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  5
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  7
análisis 5 de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método3_de_los_elementos_finitos 4
elemento 4 finito   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de4_los_elementos_finitos 5
elementos3 finitos  http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
finite element-1 method http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  2
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método5_de_los_elementos5_finitos    7
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work at all:

```
cat test | awk 'NF>=3' >> cleaned_test
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "third column" but copy/paste is giving me spaces as the delimiters. Can you clarify?

Comment: Delimiters should be tabs. First column is of simple strings, second one is of url strings and third one should be numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example data, it looks like the lines you want *also* have URL's. Here's an `awk` that checks for http (or https) and a number at the end of the line:

```
$: awk '/https*:\/\// && / [0-9]+/ { print }' file
análisis de elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  4
elemento finito http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  5
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  7
análisis 5 de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método3_de_los_elementos_finitos 4
elemento 4 finito   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de4_los_elementos_finitos 5
elementos3 finitos  http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
finite element-1 method http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  2
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método5_de_los_elementos5_finitos    7
```

If you have distinct column delimiters aside from the spaces that are apparently embedded in your column 1, we can use that. I added tabs. Now I can specifically check the third column for a number.

```
$: awk -F'\t' '{if($3~/[0-9]+/){print}}' file
análisis de elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  4
elemento finito http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  5
elementos finitos       http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
elementos finitos       http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
método de elementos finitos     http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  7
análisis 5 de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método3_de_los_elementos_finitos 4
elemento 4 finito       http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de4_los_elementos_finitos 5
elementos3 finitos      http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
finite element-1 method http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  2
método de elementos finitos     http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método5_de_los_elementos5_finitos        7
```

Comment: This is logic but `awk -F'      ' '{if($3~/[0-9]+/){print}}' file` does not filter any line and `awk '/https*:\/\// && / [0-9]+/ { print }' file` return these 2 lines: `análisis 5 de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método3_de_los_elementos_finitos 4` and
`elemento 4 finito       http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de4_los_elementos_finitos 5`

Comment: Okey, it works with this: `awk -F '\t' '{if($3~/[0-9]+/){print}}' file`. Thank you very much.

Comment: I had a tab there. Will update to the clearer representation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number is at the end of the line, we can use the following [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) command to show all lines ending with a number:

```sh
grep '[0-9]$' test.txt
```

---

Example on my local machine:

```
$ cat test.txt
análisis de elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  4
análisis de elementos finitos
elemento finito http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  5
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
elementos finitos
finite element method   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  2
finite element method   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos
finite element method
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  7
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos
método de los elementos
$
$
$ grep '[0-9]$' test.txt
análisis de elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  4
elemento finito http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  5
elementos finitos   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  29
finite element method   http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  2
método de elementos finitos http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Método_de_los_elementos_finitos  7
$
```

Comment: Does it work if some strings have numbers in it?

Comment: Please clarify, you mean something like `"12"`?

Comment: I mean something like "elemento finito 12" or "elemento finito12". I have edited input and output in the question.

Comment: Mm I don't see any other examples in your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean that now the content of input file has changed, and also the output.